# XElement.Descendant seems not getting right element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm not getting what I expect from the code below. I have many elements of "VectorScaleRange". I want to get all of those elements and, for each of them, I want to get nested elements named "MaxScale" and "MinScale". The problem is that at each cycle I get value "151" for xElmVectorScaleRange and I get null elements for xElmMinScale and xElmMaxScale

Any idea about what's wrong?...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder strXml= new StringBuilder();

            strXml.AppendLine("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
            strXml.AppendLine("<LayerDefinition xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' version='1.3.0' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='LayerDefinition-1.3.0.xsd'>");
            strXml.AppendLine("  <VectorLayerDefinition>");
            strXml.AppendLine("    <VectorScaleRange>");
            strXml.AppendLine("      <MaxScale>151</MaxScale>");
            strXml.AppendLine("      <MinScale>0</MinScale>");
            strXml.AppendLine("    </VectorScaleRange>");
            strXml.AppendLine("    <VectorScaleRange>");
            strXml.AppendLine("      <MaxScale>222</MaxScale>");
            strXml.AppendLine("      <MinScale>0</MinScale>");
            strXml.AppendLine("    </VectorScaleRange>");
            strXml.AppendLine("  </VectorLayerDefinition>");
            strXml.AppendLine("</LayerDefinition>");

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(strXml.ToString());                

            //get all vector scale ranges  
            foreach (XElement xElmVectorScaleRange in xDoc.Descendants("VectorScaleRange").Elements())
            {
                //check for scale
                XElement xElmMinScale = xElmVectorScaleRange.Descendants("MinScale").FirstOrDefault();
                XElement xElmMaxScale = xElmVectorScaleRange.Descendants("MaxScale").FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Not related to your question, but you might like the `@""` syntax, which allows you to write strings with newlines directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, very helpful this use of @""

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
foreach (XElement xElmVectorScaleRange in xDoc.Descendants("VectorScaleRange").Elements())
```

to

```
foreach (XElement xElmVectorScaleRange in xDoc.Descendants("VectorScaleRange"))
```

`Descendants` method already gives you the element you need, but you're calling `Descendants().Elements()` which leads to return elements inside `VectorScaleRange`. And there is no another level of nesting there, so obviously you get `null` when you call `xElmVectorScaleRange.Descendants("MinScale")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
...in xDoc.Descendants("VectorScaleRange").Elements())
```

You're looping through the [elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the `VectorScaleRange`s (i.e. `xElmVectorScaleRange` is each `Min` and `MaxScale`), when you seem to want to loop through the `VectorScaleRange`s themselves. Your code then looks for descendants of those elements with the right name, and finds none (all `null`s).

It also appears that there will be at most one descendant that's `Min` or `MaxScale`, and always an immediate descendant, so [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) makes more sense than [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
foreach (XElement xElmVectorScaleRange in xDoc.Descendants("VectorScaleRange"))
{
    //check for scale
    XElement xElmMinScale = xElmVectorScaleRange.Element("MinScale");
    XElement xElmMaxScale = xElmVectorScaleRange.Element("MaxScale");
}
```